# Absence of compilation error when using parametrized constructor

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

Today at work I came across a behavior in C++ which I don't understand. I have produced the following example code to illustrate my problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyException
{
    public:
        MyException(std::string s1) {std::cout << "MyException constructor, s1: " << s1 << std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    const char * text = "exception text";
    std::cout << "Creating MyException object using std::string(const char *)." << std::endl;
    MyException my_ex(std::string(text));
    std::cout << "MyException object created." << std::endl;
    //throw my_ex;

    std::string string_text("exception text");
    std::cout << "Creating MyException object using std::string." << std::endl;
    MyException my_ex2(string_text);
    std::cout << "MyException object created." << std::endl;
    // throw my_ex2;

    return 0;
}
```

This code snippet compiles without any errors and produces the following output:

```
 $ g++ main.cpp
 $ ./a.out
Creating MyException object using std::string(const char *).
MyException object created.
Creating MyException object using std::string.
MyException constructor, s1: exception text
MyException object created.
```

Note that for `my_ex` the constructor I have defined was not called. Next, if I want to actually throw this variable:

```cpp
throw my_ex;
```

I get a compilation error:

```
 $ g++ main.cpp
/tmp/ccpWitl8.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `my_ex(std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I add braces around the conversion, like this:

```cpp
const char * text = "exception text";
std::cout << "Creating MyException object using std::string(const char *)." << std::endl;
MyException my_ex((std::string(text)));
std::cout << "MyException object created." << std::endl;
throw my_ex;
```

Then it works as I would have expected:

```
 $ g++ main.cpp
 $ ./a.out
Creating MyException object using std::string(const char *).
MyException constructor, s1: exception text
MyException object created.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why does my first example compile? How come I don't get a compilation error?
2. Why **doesn't** the code compile, when I try to `throw my_ex;`?
3. Why do the braces resolve the problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), `MyException my_ex(std::string(text));` is a function declaration; the function is named `my_ex`, taking a parameter named `text` with type `std::string`, returns `MyException`. It's not an object definition at all, then no constructor will be called.

Note the error message `undefined reference to 'my_ex(std::string)'` for `throw my_ex;` (you're trying to throw a function pointer in fact), which means that can't find the definition of the function `my_ex`.

To fix it you can add additional parentheses (as you has shown) or use [braces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which supported from C++11:

```
MyException my_ex1((std::string(text)));
MyException my_ex2{std::string(text)};
MyException my_ex3{std::string{text}};
```

Comment: This is probably the most infuriating quirk of C++.

Comment: @GillBates Especially in such a complex scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this syntax, hence my bafflement at the situation.

Comment: because of this very quirk I *always* use brace initialization when possible.

Comment: `MyException my_ex(static_cast<std::string>(text))` also works ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d17dc18d4785c50d)).

Comment: `MyException ex{ {text} }`.

Comment: @black Just `MyException ex{text}` is fine. You don't need the second set of braces.

Comment: `throw MyException(text);`

Comment: Why does not my_ex2 creation require extra parentheses, though it also calls the same constructor?

Comment: @SeshadriR Because braces can't be used for the parameter list, so no ambiguous grammar issue for it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use `{}` (braced-init) as much as possible. Sometimes, though, it might be missed inadvertently. Luckily, compilers (like clang, under no extra warning flags) can hint:

```
warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    MyException my_ex(std::string(text));
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:13:23: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
    MyException my_ex(std::string(text));
                      ^
                      (                )
1 warning generated.
```

which will immediately point you the issue.